# C# - StringBuilder - Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, string, gzip, streamreader

I am trying to decompress a gzip stream. I am using a StringBuilder to read the content from the stream and do some manipulation to get it into a format that I would like to use. After decompressing the stream, the size of the string builder object is roughly 100MB. When trying to convert that String Builder to a string using the ToString Method, I get an out of memory exception. I have posted a snippet of my code below. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
using (var gzip = new GZipStream(BlobStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(gzip))
    {
        //Return early if no need to do conversions
        if (!asJson)
        {
            return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        while((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            //internal processing happens here
            sb.Append($"{line},");
        }
    }
}
sb.Replace(',', ']', sb.Length - 1, 1);
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: So why not return either the string builder or a new Stream? What do you plan on doing with the resulting `string` instance?

Comment: I want to send the string to CosmosDB using newtonsoft. I don't think newtonsoft accepts the StringBuilder or Stream. I am not sure on this but if I am wrong, please inform me.

Comment: Newtonsoft is a tool used for manipulating json, not a tool used for sending. How is it stored in CosmosDB? There might be a better approach to where you can bypass the json library.

Comment: Maybe you could write the gzip stream out to a file, and then process the file separately

Comment: Sorry, that's what I mean. I use newtonsoft for manipulating of json, I then take that result and send it to a stored procedure which handles the upsertiing to CosmosDB

Comment: Some helpful links: [Performance Tips](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm), [newtonsoft large json](https://www.google.com/search?q=newtonsoft+large+json+site:stackoverflow.com)